# how to get value of property using indeхer format

Tags: c#, visual-studio, attributes, indexer

I have some class:

```
class Issue
    {
        public decimal prjId { get; set; }
        public string prjKey { get; set; }
        public decimal issueId { get; set; }
        public string issueKey { get; set; }
        public decimal customId { get; set; }
        public string priority { get; set; }
        public string env { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public DateTime deadlineQc { get; set; }
        public string defectType { get; set; }
        public string assignee { get; set; }
        public StatusHistory statusHistory { get; set; }        
    }
```

For my purposes I need to get value of any class's property using indeхer format, for instance:

```
Issue issue = new Issue();
var c = issue.Fields["Customer ID"].Value
```

It would be equivalent:

```
c = issue.customId;
```

And for every property of my class I need this kind of сonformance.

Could anyone give me example to implement this?

**upd:** I'm sorry maybe my example above wasn't correct. In general It will be nice if It's implemented like this:

var c = issue.Fields["Customer ID"].Value

Comment: You're confusing things. Your class is an entity to store properties of a single object (so wrong name, `Issue` would be better). You could have another class that holds multiple of this in a collection like a `List<JiraIDs>` or `Dictionary<decimal, JiraIDs>`. In this class it would make sense to add an indexer property that returns a sigle instance by ID.

Comment: Thanx for advice about naming convention. I don't need to Enumerable thing. I need to get appropriate property using string attribute. In my case it's kind of meta information for every properties of my class.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can use *Reflection* like this

```
  using System.Reflection;
  ... 
  class JiraIDs {
    private static Dictionary<String, String> s_PropertiesMap = 
      new Dictionary<String, String>() {

      {"Customer ID", "customId"},
      ...
    };

    private PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo(String name) {
      String propertyName;

      if (!s_PropertiesMap.TryGetValue(name, out propertyName))
        propertyName = name;

      return GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    } 
    ...
    public object this[String name] {
      get {
        return GetPropertyInfo(name).GetValue(this, new object[0]);
      }
      set {
        GetPropertyInfo(name).SetValue(this, value);
      }   
    }
  }
```

However, I doubt if you really want this. Please, notice that as far as you have properties with *different* types (`String`, `DateTime`, `decimal` to name a few) variable `c` should be `Object` (since compiler can't predict other type at *compile time*)

```
  JiraIDs issue = new JiraIDs ();
  issue["Customer ID"] = 123M; 
  var c = issue["Customer ID"]; // c is Object
```

**Edit:**

If you want to use Attributes, e.g.

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
 public sealed class MyPropertyAliasAttribute: Attribute {
   public String Alias {get; private set; }

   public MyPropertyAliasAttribute(String alias) {
     Alias = alias;
   }
 }
```

You have to change mapping a bit:

```
   class JiraIDs {
     private static Dictionary<String, String> s_PropertiesMap; // no explict fill

     static JiraIDs() {
       s_PropertiesMap = typeof(JiraIDs).GetProperties()
         .SelectMany(property => 
           Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(property)
             .OfType<MyPropertyAliasAttribute>()
             .Select(attribute => new {
                Alias = attribute.Alias,
                Property = property.Name 
              }))
         .ToDictionary(record => record.Alias, 
                       record => record.Property);
     }
     ...
     [MyPropertyAlias("Customer ID")]
     public decimal customId { get; set; }
     ...
```

Comment: Thanx for answer! If I don't find some solution I'll take yours.

I think to use c#  attributes for textual name of properties, but don't know how.

Comment: @Ilya: Have you designed attribute so far? Say, `MyProperyNameAttribute`? If so, the task is quite easy: enumerate all properties, read your attributes on them, fill `s_PropertiesMap`

Comment: no, I haven't. I've never used attributes. I've just read about it. But now I can't figure out how to implement them for my purpose. But I feel it can be helpful for my case.

Comment: @Ilya: I see; usually, attributes are easy to implement (see my edit)

Comment: ou! awesome, I'll try this and notify asap. Thanx

Comment: @Ilya: sorry for typo `static {}` is Java syntax; `static JiraIDs()` is C#

Comment: Thanx! 
constructor cannot be static because GetType nonstatic. It's one error from Visual Studio. I remove static keyword, bu another error: 
'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'SelectMany' and no extension method 'SelectMany' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Ilya: `typeof(JiraIDs)` instead of `GetType()`